# how to find id of foreign key in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, foreign-keys

I have two entities viz:

State

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "State")
public class StateEntity {

   @Column(name = "id", length = 36, nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String id;

  @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "InsurerId", nullable = false)
  private InsurerEntity insurer;

  @Column(name ="StateName", length = 50, nullable = false)
  private String stateName;

//getters and setters

}
```

Insurer

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Insurer")
public class InsurerEntity {

  @Column(name = "InsurerId", length = 36, nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String insurerId;

  @Column(name = "InsurerName", length = 100, nullable = true)
  private String insurerName;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "state", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<StateEntity> stateEntityList;

//getters and setters

}
```

the insurer's id gets saved in **state** database and I want to retrieve it using hibernate query but I cant't seem to find the solution for that

How to write this query `SELECT InsurerId FROM State;` in Hibernate query using `CriteriaBuilder`, `CriteriaQuery` and `Root`..

Comment: `SELECT insurer.insurerIdFROM State;`

Comment: @AlexanderTerekhov Is it possible for you do the same using `CriteriaBuilder`, `CriteriaQuery` and `Root`...please

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all Insurers's Ids for all states:

```
String selectionQuery = "SELECT s.insurer.insurerId FROM State s";
List<String> insurersIds = session.createQuery(selectionQuery).list();
```

If you want to select the Insurer's Id of a certain state:

```
String selectionQuery = "SELECT s.insurer.insurerId FROM State s WHERE s.id = :stateId";
String insurerId = (String) session.createQuery(selectionQuery).setParameter("stateId", stateId).getSingleResult(); //This should be placed in a try/catch block to handle org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException
```

**Edit**:

You should update your Insurer entity as Prasad wrote in his answer.

Comment: Is it possible for you do the same using `CriteriaBuilder`, `CriteriaQuery` and `Root`...please

Comment: @Cybertronian Sorry for being too late. Are you still interested in an answer to your question in the comment?

Comment: Yes I'm still interested.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to map both the class as in put @oneToMany annotation in class InsurerEntity as well

`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="StateEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

`private List< StateEntity > StateEntitys;`

and when you fetch states you will also get object of InsurerEntity in it from where you can access it with the getter

Comment: Given that the fetching session is still open because otherwise he will get LazyInitializationException.